# Inclusion in validation and Rspec using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having troubles testing an ActiveRecord inclusion validation in Rails with Factory Girl and Rspec.  The inclusion validation always fails.  Here is my code:

```
class FruitType
  has_many :fruits
end

class Fruit
  belongs_to :fruit_type
  validates :fruit_type_id, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :fruit_type_id, inclusion: { in: FruitType.pluck(:id), message: "is invalid" }
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :fruit_type_apple, class: FruitType do
     name "Apple"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :valid_fruit, class: Fruit do
    name "Red Apple"
    association :fruit_type, factory: :fruit_type_apple
  end
end
```

Rspec test is:

```
it "should have valid factory" do
  f = FactoryGirl.build( :valid_fruit )
  puts f.fruit_type_id
  puts "\n#{FruitType.all.pluck(:id)}"
  expect(f).to be_valid
end
```

Result is:

1

[1]
F..........

Failures:

1) Fruit when validated should have valid factory
    Failure/Error: expect(f).to be_valid
    expected # to be valid, but got errors: Fruit type is invalid

As you can see, I've printed out the Fruit Type id list in the test, which includes only 1.  And I've printed out the value of fruit_type_id for the fruit, which is 1.  Yet, the inclusion validation still fails.

If I do the same thing in the rails console just by creating fruits and types manually, the validation works fine, it's just when I run the test I'm seeing this behavior.  Any ideas?  I must be missing something about Factory Girl here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't validate the `fruit_type_id` attribute, rather use presence validation

```
validates :fruit_type, presence: true
```

Comment: Are you saying to remove both the numericality and inclusion in validation, and replace with simply presence?  Will that validate both scenarios (the user entered say "A" for fruit_type_id, or they entered 9999 as the fruit_type_id, and I don't have that type of fruit)?

Comment: Yes, remove both. Try playing with wrong values and see for yourself.

Comment: Oh man.  Can I tip you?  Your suggestion has worked.

A simple Google search turned up (regarding validates presence):
"Validates that the specified attributes are not blank (as defined by Object#blank?), and, if the attribute is an association, that the associated object is not marked for destruction"

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of